# What exactly is the difference between the is_callable and function_exists in PHP?

Tags: php

I am working on a project, in which I am using a deprecated function from the older version. But don't want my script to stop if used in the older version.

So I am checking if the function exists and if not then create it.

What is the difference between `function_exists` and `is_callable` in PHP and which one is better to use?

```
if (!is_callable('xyz')) {
    function xyz() {
       // code goes here
    }
}
```

OR

```
if(!function_exists('xyz')) {
    function xyz() {
      // code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The function [`is_callable`](http://php.net/is_callable) accepts not only function names, but also other types of [callbacks](http://php.net/callback):

- `Foo::method`
- `array("Foo", "method")`
- `array($obj, "method")`
- Closures and other invokable objects (PHP 5.3)

So `is_callable` accepts anything that you could pass [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) and family, while [`function_exists`](http://php.net/function_exists) only tells if a certain function exists (not methods, see [`method_exists`](http://php.net/method_exists) for that, nor closures).

Put another way, `is_callable` is a wrapper for [`zend_is_callable`](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_API.c#3035), which handles variables with the pseudo-type callback, while `function_exists` only does a [hash table lookup](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#1295) in the functions' table.

Comment: In a case that `method` is a public method of `Foo` and "Foo" is not initialized, `is_callable('Foo', 'method')` returned `false` while `method_exists('Foo', 'method')` returned `true`. Ps. I tested this inside a `foreach (get_declared_classes() as $class)` loop.

Answer (score 12):

When used with a function (not a class method) there is no difference except that `function_exists` is slightly faster.

But when used to check the existence of methods in a class you **cannot** use `function_exists`. You'll have to use `is_callable` or `method_exists`.

Answer (score 10):

When used in class context, `is_callable` returns true for class methods that are accessible ie public methods but `method_exists` returns true for all methods - public, protected and private. `function_exists` does same thing as `method_exists` outside class contexts.

Answer (score 3):

If a function `Plop` exists then `function_exists("Plop")` will return true.

See [`function_exists`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

If a variable is callable then `is_callable($var)` will return true.
Now this could mean that `$var` is a function name.
But i could also be an object and method name combo.

See [`is_callable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)

Answer (score 3):

One more different:

If you have a class which uses [`__call` magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), the `is_callable($object, $method)` will always return true for anything because `__call` basically accepts every method name. And as you might already know, `method_exists` will return false for this if the method is not defined in the class.

This is especially annoying if you use CakePHP `Model` class as they implemented `__call` magic method to provide magic queries, but not cool if you want the method to be absolutely defined.

Comment: I faced this situation in Laravel