# Using array_map with multi-argument function?

Tags: php, array-map

I am building a recursive function, which executes any function for any-deep-nested-array. For example, I want to STRIPSLASH all array values in this:

```
function RECURSER($array,$function_name){ 
   return is_array($array) ? array_map('RECURSER', $array, $function_name) : $function_name($array); 
}
```

but when I execute:

```
recursive_for_array_value( $MY_ARRAY, 'stripslashes')
```

the above function can't send second parameter to `array_map`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3912930/3933332

Comment: @T.Todua I upvoted your question and answer here because this is a cool challenge.  Did you actually need this for a project, or was this a theoretical mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I'll start off by saying that I'd probably never use this in any real projects, but this is an interesting challenge/question and T.Todua's answer works but using `$GLOBALS` can be avoided.

My position is that `array_walk_recursive()` is a better suited function versus recursively calling `array_map()` -- after all, `array_walk_recursive()` was specifically designed to visit leaf nodes and avoid the tedium of checking the current item's type as "array".  `use()` is effective in passing the function string into the recursive function's scope.

*Note:  You *could* only pass the function string as [a string in a SUPER fringe case where the function prints to screen AND requires two arguments -- the first arg being the element value and the second arg being the element key](https://3v4l.org/qLvWL).

Because you want to only process the element values AND modify them by reference, `&$v` is necessary.

Here is a relevant post to read regarding checking the dynamic function name: [What exactly is the difference between the is_callable and function_exists in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3499736/2943403)

Here is my working alternative:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cLbE0))

```
$multidim_array = ['a' => [' \one ', ['b' => 'two\\', [['c' => 'thr\ee']]]]];
$func = 'stripslashes';
if (function_exists($func)) {
    array_walk_recursive($multidim_array, function(&$v)use($func){$v = $func($v);});
    var_export($multidim_array);
} else {
    echo "not callable";
}
```

---

If you wanted to go down this rabbit hole further, you *could* extend its potential utility by setting up the option to pass multiple arguments:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5LUlp))

```
$func = 'strpos';
if (function_exists($func)) {
    $more = true;
    $param2 = 'o';
    array_walk_recursive($multidim_array, function(&$v)use($func, $more, $param2) {
        if ($more) {
            $v = $func($v, $param2);
        } else {
            $v = $func($v);
        }
    });
    var_export($multidim_array);
} else {
    echo "um... I'm not calling $func";
}
```

---

Finally, the approach that I whole-heartedly do NOT endorse is the use of [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) -- because you can see the tail, horns, and pitchfork a mile away.

> Caution
>   The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

This works, but really should not be entertained:

```
if (function_exists($func)) {
    array_walk_recursive($multidim_array, function(&$v)use($func) {eval("\$v = $func(\$v);"); });
    var_export($multidim_array);
} else {
    echo "um... I'm not calling $func";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_map` accepts one function and multiple arrays as arguments. Perhaps you need to recursively call recurser via an anonymous function instead.

```
function RECURSER($array,$function_name){ 
     if (is_array($array))
        return array_map(function ($element) use ($function_name) {
           return RECURSER($element,$function_name);
       },$array);                
   return $function_name($array);
}
```

The usecase of `stripslashes` as a one-line PHP function can be written as :

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value) { $value = stripslashes($value); });
```

Comment: your `array_walk_recursive()` example is not dynamic and the OP is asking for a dynamic solution.  Can you show me a demo of your first code block so that I can see it working?

Comment: @mickmackusa http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0215f35be3252a99ac86a94107c75f7464d91a3

Answer (score 1):

## RECURSOR of any function:

`$result= Recursiver_of_Array($array, 'stripslashes');`

code:

```
function Recursiver_of_Array($array,$function_name=false){ 
    if ($function_name) { $GLOBALS['current_func_name']= $function_name; }
    return is_array($array) ? array_map('Recursiver_of_Array', $array) : $GLOBALS['current_func_name']($array); 
}
```